# What simple web server script will accept text on a LAN?

Tags: linux, scripting, webserver, iphone

I want to dump iphone notes (text) to my Linux box, but don't want to route the data through the Internet.  I can get a LAN IP via WiFi on the iphone and the LAN is firewalled, so I should be able to setup a simple web server on the Linux box that behaves like pastebin - that is, the web server sends a page that awaits text in an input box and saves it when the user presses a button. I usually run Linux Mint.

Comment: What you're asking is a programming question, even if your desired environment is Linux. You could try reposting this in another more relevant exchange.

Comment: Thank you.  I found the answer.
github.com/xumingming/simple-pastebin-server/blob/master/pastebin.py

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do it that way, but rather than all that copying and pasting, wouldn't it be easier to set up your local web server as a local ssh server, then scp the text files on the iPhone to it?

On your server, apt-get install ssh, run it, then adjust your firewall to allow incoming connections on port 22 from the local network.

Then copy your notes like this:

> scp -r /directory/where/your/notes/are fred@192.168.1.##:/directory/where/you/want/notes/to/be